# Python decimal range() step by step value

Tags: python

I wants to check all combination values which satisfy the conditions given in if statement

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step   

for a in drange(0.1, 0.9,0.1):
    for b in drange(0.1, 0.9,0.1):
        for c in drange(0.1, 0.9,0.1):
            if a+b+c == 1 and a>b>c:
                print a
                print b
                print c
```

It is working but doesn't give the all combinations.

Comment: There should be four combinations but it give only three combinations. It miss a=0.7  b=0.2  c=0.1

Comment: Or, in other words, why `print 0.7+0.2+0.1 == 1` returns `False` ? :)

Comment: You could change `drange(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)` to `drange(1, 9, 1)` and compare `a+b+c = 10` as a workaround. When printing out information, do `print a/10.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you’re running into here is essentially the problem behind floating point alrithmetic. See [this question for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/216074) about what’s going on and why it happens.

To sum it up, just look at the results from your `drange(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)`:

```
>>> list(drange(0.1, 0.9, 0.1))
[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999]
```

As you can see, you don’t get exact results there. So when you sum them up, you won’t get an exact `1`.

Instead, when comparing floats with rounded numbers, you should always allow for some kind of precision loss. One way to do that is to take the difference and see if it’s below some threshold (in this case, I chose `0.00001`):

```
if abs((a + b + c) - 1) < 0.00001:
    print('The sum is likely 1')
```

So in your case, your code could look like this:

```
for a in drange(0.1, 0.9, 0.1):
    for b in drange(0.1, 0.9, 0.1):
        for c in drange(0.1, 0.9, 0.1):
            if abs((a + b + c) - 1) < 0.00001 and a > b > c:
                print a
                print b
                print c
```

And that will safely produce the expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is working properly and I got understand the reason.

Comment: @Upendra Glad it is working for you. Please remember to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) if it solved your problem to mark this question as resolved.